# How to create database's name in cmd which one has a dash

Tags: mysql, sql, database

When I write this code it is not working.

```
CREATE DATABASE blabla-bla;
```

Comment: 1. Don't do it 2. Wrap your database name in backticks

Comment: If you really need a separator, use an underscore.

Comment: Thanks man it is working

Answer (score 1):

You can use punctuation, whitespace, and so on in SQL by using *delimited identifiers*. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifiers.html for more information on this.

MySQL delimited identifiers are back-ticks by default.

```
CREATE DATABASE `blabla-bla`;
```

As @JohnConde commented, it's easier to use SQL if you avoid cases when you need to use delimited identifiers.

Comment: I got it.Thank you too.I should use mysql